# Как вывести текст на определенной странице сайта с динамическим окончанием?

Tags: php

Есть код который выводит текст на определенной странице:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/questions/') { ?>
    сюда включаем нужный код или текст
    <?php }  ?>
```

А как прописать в этом коде страницу с меняющимся url на конце. Например: `/questions/abc`

```
abc → меняющаяся часть ссылки.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
if ( preg_match('/\/questions\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
```

Comment: Товарищ @a-k, после вашей правки код стал не рабочим - лишние слэши. Правильно '/\/questions\//'

Comment: Спасибо все работает!

Comment: М-м-м, разве? Посмотрел в [историю правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/906287/revisions) - там видно, что я только добавил 4 пробела, чтобы код стал отображаться как блок кода.

Comment: Вы правы. [Запостил баг на мету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8252/213987).

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); 
$result = array_pop(explode("/", trim($path, "/")));
switch ($result) {
    case('abc'): ... break;
    case('def'): ... break;
    и т.д. 
}
```

Comment: А если ссылок более 1 миллиона?

Comment: Во-первых, в вопросе об этом ничего не сказано. Во-вторых, судя по указанному в вопросе коду это вряд ли.